# USB Type-C sink states

Tags: digital-logic, analog, signal, usb-c, verification

I'm a Digital engineer. I'm trying to understand how to write a testbench to verify the fsm state transitions in USB type C when acting as a sink, sink with accessory support and sink with try_sink and accessory support. I cannot understand how to verify the values or what values to consider at the receptacle pins. I need to transition between different states please explain which pins correspond to state transitions.